# Does google search API eliminate stop words?

Tags: google-app-engine, search

Consider if your search query in google search API is "I Love you". 
In this query, "I" and "you" are stop words and they occur in almost every document. The keyword(s) present in this search is "Love" which should be searched for. So, there must be a process to detect the stop words and eliminate them from the document list we feed to the API. Does google do it automatically in their search API or do we have to process the search query before firing the query? If google already uses the IDF (Inverse Document Frequency) table to eliminate (or less - prioritise) the stop words, how do they do it? If not, how can we eliminate those stop words? Does the algorithm (if any) works for other (vernacular) languages too?

Link to Google search API [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/search/)

Comment: they are not eliminated but you have control over what you give to the index.

Answer (score 0):

Google full text search api does not eliminate stop words.

If you perform a global search with search query "I Love you", you will only get documents which will have all the 3 words and not just *stop words*

> The white space between words, quoted strings, numbers, and dates is
>   treated as an implicit AND operator.

If you want the same functionality while searching within a field here is one approach to look for:

If you enclose your query between parentheses then search will only return documents that contains all the words in the query.

For the case "I Love you", search query should be:

```
field_name = "(I Love You)"
```

or

```
field_name = "(I AND Love AND You)"
```

This way you will only get documents that contain all the words and not just *stop words*.

Answer (score 0):

You can just search for the word "Love" in the index.
If you want to search for the word anywhere in the text, you can use wild card operator *

```
field_name = "Love*"
```